# Integration tests : How to load different proxy settings depending on the environment

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, environment-variables, integration-testing

I'm developing integrations tests with Selenium Webdriver on .NET Core
- On local, a proxy is needed to access the website I want to test
- But on stage it is the opposite: No proxy must be set (or it will make the website unreachable)

My code looks like this:

**Test example:**

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
public class LoginPageTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestLoginPageDisplaysWell()
    {
        using (var scope = new TestScope())
        {
            var page = new LoginPage(scope.Driver);
            page.GoTo();

            // Page
            Assert.AreEqual(expected: "Index", actual: page.BrowserTitle);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected: "Login", actual: page.ContentTitle.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

**TestScope class:**

```
private sealed class TestScope : IDisposable
{
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; }

    public TestScope()
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();

        // Proxy settings
        var proxySettings = default(Proxy);
        var proxySettingsSection = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("testsettings.json")
        .Build()
        .GetSection("ProxySettings");

        if (proxySettingsSection.Exists())
        {
            proxySettings = new Proxy();
            proxySettingsSection.Bind(proxySettings);
            options.Proxy = proxySettings;
        }

        options.AddArgument("--headless");

        Driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Driver?.Quit();
    }
}
```

**testsettings.json:**

```
{
    "ProxySettings": {
        "Kind": "Manual",
        "IsAutoDetect": false,
        "SslProxy": "_PROXY_ADDRESS_"
    }
}
```

How I can load different proxy settings depending on the environment ?

All the solutions I found involved checking ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to load specific testsettings.{environmentName} file
But this works only on web solutions hosted on IIS

My project is a test project: I did not found a way to specify any environment information to the test runner

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach the issue would be to use multiple JSON settings files, and use different deployment tooling to ensure that the right one is deployed based on the test environment (local vs. staging).

Another way would be to rework your test setting file to contain multiple configurations and a property that loads the active one at runtime. For example:

```
{
  "ActiveConfig": "local",
  "TestConfigs": {
    "local": {
      "ProxySettings": {
        "Kind": "Manual",
        "IsAutoDetect": false,
        "SslProxy": "_PROXY_ADDRESS_"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside, most test runners have a way to specify a parameter on the command line. For NUnit’s console runner, for example, that’s `--testparam` (though the console runner doesn’t support .NET Core tests yet), and you can use that to tell the test which config is active. Failing that, an environment variable could easily serve the same purpose.